# How to merge branch from another worktree

Tags: git, git-branch, git-worktree

I have a repo with 2 banch: master and b1.

Currently, the checkout branch is master (in main worktree).

I create a worktree (called b1_worktree) and checkout the b1 branch by default.

So now I can work on both branch without using "checkout" command.

And this is my questions:

- After changing the code in branch b1 in b1_worktree, how can I merged b1 from b1_worktree to master branch in main worktree?
- And is it possible to update the b1 content from b1_worktree to main worktree?

Comment: Branches are not linked to any worktree. Both are accessible through each worktree.

Comment: @eftshift0 Haha, we're definitely linked in some way ;-) Take care

Comment: I even tried contacting you on linkedin but never heard back. :-P

Comment: @eftshift0 Oh I'm sorry! This is basically a ghost account I created a long time ago and never came back. Try the mail on my website for better results...

Answer (score 1):

To git, once you commit something on `b1_worktree`, it will move `b1` branch, which will be visible on the original worktree. So just merge `b1` there and the change should magically work.

Comment: I tried committing something on b1_worktree.
After delete the b1_worktree, the commit of the b1_branch in b1_worktree is "automatically" update to original worktree.

What should I do if I want to update commit of b1 from b1_worktree to original worktree manually?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I read the comment from @Romain
Now I understand the root.
Thank you both.

Answer (score 0):

If need to merge from worktree HEAD (e.g. in detach mode),
then please see https://git-scm.com/docs/git-worktree#_refs

> Refs that are per-worktree can still be accessed from another worktree via two special paths, main-worktree and worktrees. The former gives access to per-worktree refs of the main worktree, while the latter to all linked worktrees.

> For example, main-worktree/HEAD or main-worktree/refs/bisect/good resolve to the same value as the main worktree’s HEAD and refs/bisect/good respectively. Similarly, worktrees/foo/HEAD or worktrees/bar/refs/bisect/bad are the same as $GIT_COMMON_DIR/worktrees/foo/HEAD and $GIT_COMMON_DIR/worktrees/bar/refs/bisect/bad.